# Generic logic for replacing a single value in FormGroup with a custom value

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formgroups

I am using Angular 6. I have a student registration form. Fields: name, address, phone, batch.

In the backend, i have one table for student and another table for batch(which has its own properties eg: id, name, schedule...).

Now, in the student registration form UI, i need to display a single selection dropdown for batch(names). But when saving, i should save id in the student table.

current output of formGroup.value:
{ name:"john", address: "12 Main St", phone: "22421231234", batch: "Batch 1" }

Instead, i need,
{ name:"john", address: "12 Main St", phone: "22421231234", batch: "id#" }

I know two solutions, one i can manually create the json without using the formgroup, i can have a model and keep updating values as user enters. Second, i can replace batch with the id. (This will not be robust if i do a search with name in my array as my array might have multiple items with the same name)

Any other easy solution to manage this?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use a model class to change your form,value in required form.

```
 export class Student
{
  name:string;
  address:string;
  phone:string;
  Batch :number;
constructor()
{
}
map(input:any)
{
  this.name=input.name;
   this.address=input.address;
    this.phone=input.phone;
     this.Batch=batchService.getIdbyName(input.Batch);

}
```

use this model in your component.ts 
like this let json=new Student().map(form.value);

Comment: batchService is your service which will provide batch id. you can provide it in constructor

Comment: Appreciate your quick response. What if, there are multiple entries with same name.?

Comment: then bind batch id in value and show batch name. Please Accept answer if you find it useful